# Correct way to identify stack areas of Pthreads

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I want to identify the stack areas of pthreads (on Linux), for this I am using a kernel module to walk through the VMAs of the process (as I have learned that stack areas of pthreads are allocated in the heap area of process) and checking whether **VM_STACK_FLAGS** (include/linux/mm.h) is set for the VMA, if yes, I consider the VMA as stack.

Is this approach the correct way? or Is there a better way to identify stacks for pthreads on Linux?

Thanks

Comment: Use pthread_attr_setstack

Comment: Thanks @stark, but I can not modify the application which is using pthreads, that is reason I am resorting to kernel module